# Setting up the partial fraction template for $\int \frac{3}{(x^2-6x+5)^2(x^2+x+2)^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-fractions

My Calculus 2 professor wants us to be able to set up partial fraction templates for complicated integrals. I don't know of a way to check my work without meeting with him, and he is unavailable right now, so I'm asking here.

$$\int \frac{3}{(x^2-6x+5)^2(x^2+x+2)^2}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{3}{[(x-1)(x-5)]^2(x^2+x+2)^2}dx$$

$$=\int \frac{A}{x-1}+\frac{B}{x-5}+\frac{C}{x-1}+\frac{D}{x-5} +\frac{Ex+\Delta}{x^2+x+2}+\frac{Fx+\theta}{x^2+x+2}dx$$

Is this the correct way to set up the integral to be integrated using the partial fractions method? If not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: The first two terms and the fifth term should be squared in the denominator, otherwise they just get absorbed by the next terms since $A,B,C,D,E,F,\Delta,\theta$ are all arbitrary at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $C,$ $D,$ and $Fx+\theta$ terms should have the denominator squared.  I would use Roman letters instead of the Greek in the last two terms.

Comment: Thank you! Is that everything I've gotten wrong?

Comment: Yes, the rest is OK.